# Can Android kill Fragment without killing activity that hosts it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragmentmanager, android-activitymanager

First of all I’d like to sorry if my question is dummy, I’m just starting my Android way and wasn’t able to find the answer to my question in google . I’d like to know whether Android os is able to kill only fragment(support fragment) without killing the actual activity that hold this fragment ? Thanks for your help and sorry if question is stupid !

Comment: kill the fragment means? what is your actual requirement? Please post some code of what you have tried till now

Comment: The OS does not "kill" activities or fragments. The OS can and does terminate your process when it is in the background.